# mysql2 not working after upgrading mysql to 8

Tags: macos, mysql2, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I recently updated mysql to `mysql8.0.4` from `mysql5.7`. I updated the mysql2 gem from `0.4.9` to `0.5.3`
After that I starts getting the below error :

```
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@talent_now/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:188:in `rescue in spec': 
Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
```

I tried to downgrade mysql2 to `0.4.9` but then I got

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.25_1/include/mysql/mysql.h:187:3: note: 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH' declared here
  MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH,
  ^
client.c:1315:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH'; did you mean 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH'?
  return _mysql_client_options(self, MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH, value);
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                     MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.25_1/include/mysql/mysql.h:187:3: note: 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH' declared here
  MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH,
  ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [client.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

I am using `Rails5.1.4` in mac catalina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql2 0.5.x` is not compatible with `Rails5.1.4`,
so I updated `Rails` to `5.1.7` to make it work.

```
mysql2 0.5.x works with Rails / Active Record 4.2.11, 5.0.7, 5.1.6, and higher.
```

Above is mentioned on the [mysql2](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) documentation.